# warning when using primefaces (no taglib found)

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I am using pimefaces in my project and I get the following message when the page is displayed in the browser:

```
Warning: This page calls for XML namespace http://primefaces.org/ui declared with prefix p but no taglibrary exists for that namespace.
```

In my POM:

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>prime-repo</id>
        <name>PrimeFaces Maven Repository</name>
        <url>http://repository.primefaces.org</url>
        <layout>default</layout>
    </repository>
</repositories>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
        <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
        <version>3.5</version>
    </dependency>
```

In my xhtml files:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
    template="/WEB-INF/templates/default_template.xhtml">
    <ui:define name="content">
        <h1>My Stuff</h1>

        <h:form>
            <p:dataTable value="#{edb.actions}" var="action">
                <p:column>
                    <p:commandButton actionListener="#{acontroller.doDelete(aktion)}" icon="ui-icon-close" />
                </p:column>
                <p:column>
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <h:outputText value="name" />
                    </f:facet>
                    <h:outputText value="#{action.name}" />
                </p:column>
                <p:column>
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <h:outputText value="goal" />
                    </f:facet>
                    <h:outputText value="#{action.goals}">
                        <f:convertNumber type="currency" currencyCode="EUR" />
                    </h:outputText>
                </p:column>
```

.. and so on

I am using Glassfish 4.0 and EclipseEE Version: 4.3.2.

What do I need to change?

Thanks for help and tips!

EDIT:

I removed primefaces completely and now JSF tags are not displayed. I read that this may be linked to the Faces Servlet not kicking in. My web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" 
     xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    version="2.5">
    <display-name>MyProject</display-name>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.xhtml</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
        <param-value>Development</param-value>
    </context-param>

</web-app>
```

My webapp folder structure:

```
webapp
- content
--- .xhtml files
- index.xhtml
- resources
--- css
------ screen.css
- WEB-INF
- web.xml
- beans.xml (empty)
- faces.config.xml (empty)
- glassfish.web.xml (empty)
- templates
--- default_template.xhtml
```

In my POM:

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
            <version>7.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.faces</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.8</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.faces</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.faces-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
```

... and so on:

What's the problem now then?? I dont understand this. It worked perfectly until a couple of days ago...

Comment: Sorry, that's what I meant: when I call the page in the browser, I get this message. And when I inspect the sourcecode, I see tags with p:

Comment: are you sure the primefaces 3.5 jar is deployed (in WEB-INF/lib)

Comment: I didnt know that was necessary. Ive been working on this for a couple of days and only today did it stop working... I have no idea what I did differently. How do I make sure it is deployed to that folder?

Comment: Just have a look into it :) You may inspect the builded var eg with 7zip, winrar, etc...

Comment: Glassfish doesnt keep the war, as far as I can see. So i cant inspect it.

Comment: No solution for this?

Comment: We can't solve it for you.  You have to check if the primefaces jar is in your webapp.  If you can't check that something else is wrong tgat, again, only you can check

Comment: well, I removed all primefaces tags and am only using JSF 2.2 at the moment and now not even those get displayed... see my edit

Comment: Okay, well, I guess in the end I messed it up even more by changing and copying things here and there. I did everything you said and also fixed something with the template I am using and now everything works again (however, still not using primefaces). I may get back to primefaces and let you know what fixed the problem, if you're interested, but as for now I'll stick to pure JSF. Thanks a million!!